# Python PubNub subscriber doesn't print out the message

Tags: python, pubnub

This is my publisher:

```
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub

def publish_callback(result, status):
    print(result)
    print(status)
    # Handle PNPublishResult and PNStatus

pnconfig = PNConfiguration()

pnconfig.subscribe_key = 'sub-c-ec413276-b805-11e6-b737-xxxxx'
pnconfig.publish_key = 'pub-c-528502df-76a6-4f07-8636-xxxxx'

pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)

pubnub.publish().channel("awesomeChannel").message("hello!!").async(publish_callback)
```

This is my subscriber

```
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub

from pubnubtets import MySubscribeCallback
pnconfig = PNConfiguration()

pnconfig.subscribe_key = 'sub-c-ec413276-b805-11e6-b737-xxxxx'
pnconfig.publish_key = 'pub-c-528502df-76a6-4f07-8636-xxxxx'
pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)

pubnub.add_listener(MySubscribeCallback())
pubnub.subscribe().channels('awesomeChannel').execute()
```

This is my callback:

```
from pubnub.callbacks import SubscribeCallback
from pubnub.enums import PNStatusCategory

class MySubscribeCallback(SubscribeCallback):
  def presence(self, pubnub, presence):
    print(presence)

  def status(self, pubnub, status):
    if status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory:
      pass  # This event happens when radio / connectivity is lost

    elif status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory:
      # Connect event. You can do stuff like publish, and know you'll get it.
      # Or just use the connected event to confirm you are subscribed for
      # UI / internal notifications, etc
      pass
    elif status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNReconnectedCategory:
      pass
      # Happens as part of our regular operation. This event happens when
      # radio / connectivity is lost, then regained.
    elif status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNDecryptionErrorCategory:
      pass
      # Handle message decryption error. Probably client configured to
      # encrypt messages and on live data feed it received plain text.

  def message(self, pubnub, message):
    print(message)
```

The problem I have is when I run the subscriber it listens and when I run the publisher to send the message `hello!!` my callback gets it but when i print the message it prints out `<pubnub.models.consumer.pubsub.PNMessageResult object at 0x108453278>`. I want it to actually show me my message `hello!!`.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the pubnub [python sdk docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/api-reference-sdk-v4):

[image]

So try

```
print(message.message)
```